# Snackbar shown along with Toast

Tags: android, toast, android-toast, android-snackbar, snackbar

I am using Google's design support [library](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to show Snackbars. After I compile the apk and run it on phone (Nexus 5), the Snackbar is shown along with the Toast. Running directly from Android Studio works fine (only Snackbar is shown). Any help will be appreciated. How can I disable the toast and only show Snackbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I disable the toast and only show Snackbar

Simply do not use Toast. It will not show up by itself.

Comment: Yeah. I was missing a return statement. My bad. Thanks a lot.